# Running Python scripts from using PHP exec()

Tags: php, python, html

I want to run a python script in a button press event of a php/html file. I tried following. Is this possible with PHP exec()? But following didn't work. What is wrong with my code?

HTML file

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<H3>Run Python Script...</H3>
<form name="input" action="test2.php" method="get">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP exec()

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<H3>Executing...</H3>
<?php exec("first.py"); ?>
<H3>Completed...</H3>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be several problems with even your python script.

First: Can you run this script from console? (Do you have a #!/path/to/env/python in the script's beginning)?
If not, then either add it to your script or to the exec function (without #!)

You can also use `passthru` instead of exec, so you can display the raw output of the script.

Comment: Hey thanks, this 'passthru' worked for a simple script with one print line, but my script didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

`exec` Executes a command as if on the command line, running `first.py` just via bash won't work. You have two options:

**Option A**

You can tell the python parser explicitly to run the file with:

```
exec('python first.py');
```

**Option B**

Make sure your python script's first line is the path to python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#Python code...
```

Then call `exec('./first.py')`

*(If you chose this option, you'll need to make sure the script is executable)*

**Conclusion**

I'd probably go with option A as it's simplest and gets the job done without fuss.

Hope this helps :) x

Comment: Thanks Emily, got some insight :)

Answer (score 1):

try `exec("/usr/bin/python path/to/first.py")`

Comment: My answer answers his question "What is wrong with my code?" enough, it has been tested before, so if you're desperate for points and cannot add anything beneficial here , don't try to make others' answers look bad, go get a life.