# Use php code bloks inside p5.js to invoke python script

Tags: php, python, p5.js

I am trying to build a responsive interface using `p5.js`.

It uses user responses to update pyo4 object variables.

**QUESTION**

Can I use Python inside p5.js?

**QUESTION**

If I can't use Python can I use PHP inside `p5.js` and evoke Python within PHP?

---

I tried this simple example without luck:

```
var htmlString="<?php echo $htmlString;?>"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Python scripts from using PHP exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22808517/running-python-scripts-from-using-php-exec)

Comment: DyZ, that problem is about  python inside php right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to understand the difference between what happens on the server and what happens on the client.

PHP and Python happen on the server, before the page is loaded. You can use this to change what HTML is shown depending on the request, but once the page is loaded you're pretty much done.

P5.js happens on the client, after the page is loaded. You can use this to modify what's already on the page, but you can't directly interact with server code.

> Can I use Python inside p5.js?

No.

> If I can't use Python can I use PHP inside p5.js and evoke Python within PHP?

No.

What you need to do is create **requests** from your P5.js code, which can trigger an endpoint on your server. This is called **AJAX** and there are a ton of resources online about it.

Comment: Really appreciate your guidance, using AJAX . i did able to implement the update function